# What is powering the Google Translate speech synthesis feature?

Tags: text-to-speech

Does anyone know what software is behind the speech synthesis feature on Google Translate - it does a pretty good job in a number of languages.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I found;

[`eSpeak`](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/)

> `eSpeak` is a compact open source software speech synthesizer for
>   English and other languages, for Linux and Windows.

Referance : [Google Translate Adds Text-to-Speech for More Languages](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2010/05/google-translate-adds-text-to-speech.html)

Comment: @Yes, thank you, so +1, but I don't think this is what they are using.

Comment: @UpTek Why? Written on their blog. Maybe now they using better synthesizer, just we don't know

Comment: You're right! That document is over a year old though, so will have to investigate a little more to see if this has changed.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely not that any more - the sound quality is incomparable.

Answer (score -1):

Google has their own technology. If they would tell us how they do everything, no one would use their services anymore.

Comment: If you're implying that Google exclusively uses software it has built from scratch, that's plain wrong. They have also told us plenty about how they do things - I have no idea why you think people would stop using their services if they knew